# Deriving parameters of gaussian noise that will lead to bounded random walk

Tags: distributions, random-walk, noise, white-noise

Given a bound on random walk, I am trying to derive the parameters of a normal distribution of noise, which when added to a signal and integrated will lead to random walk within specified bounds.

#### My thought process slash what I've tried:

In my case, the noise in question is being added to angular velocity detected by a simulated gyro, in units of rad/sec.

So let $x_n$ be the final angle of a series of $n$ steps, where each step is drawn from a distribution with zero mean and standard deviation of $\sigma_d$:

$$\theta_n = \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}d_i$$

[As I understand it](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ecaflisch/181.1.03f/Lect4-5.pdf), this should lead to a distribution of

$$x_n \sim \mathcal{N(0, \sigma_x)} \text{ where } \sigma_x = n \sigma_d$$

Okay, now I've been given a threshold on random walk by the manufacturer that I'll call $\epsilon = 3\sigma_x$, which gives me

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\epsilon}{3} = \sigma_x = n\sigma_d \\
\rightarrow \sigma_d = \frac{\epsilon}{3n}
\end{equation}
$$

Assuming that the math above is correct, which is highly unlikely, the next hurdle I have to get over is the fact that the maximum random walk given by the manufacturer is in degrees per root hour, while the gyro operates and reports in radians per second.

So, I tried converting my units and then looking at the final resting place of a bunch of experiments like so:

```
import numpy as np

rate = 200          # hz
T = 1 / rate        # seconds
stop_time = 3600    # seconds
n = rate * stop_time 

rw_max = 0.05                         # deg / rt-hour
rw_max = rw_max * np.sqrt(1 / 3600)   # deg / rt-sec
rw_max = rw_max * (np.pi / 180)       # rad / rt-sec
rw_max = rw_max * np.sqrt(T)          # rad / sec

sigma = rw_max / (3 * n)

# generate noise
noise = np.random.normal(0, sigma, (n, 100)) 

# integrate to get random walk path of each experiment
walk = np.cumsum(noise, 0) * T

# This is the final resting place of each path in units of radians
x_n = walk[-1]
```

But the distribution of these last steps does not have the $3\sigma$ provided by the manufacturer:

[image]

I'm clearly going about this incorrectly, probably in multiple ways.

**How do I derive the angular velocity noise parameters from the manufacturer specified maximum random walk in the units of degrees per root hour?**